# When is a different question a duplicate and when it isn't?

Tags: discussion

I marked this [Whats happening if your pokemon bag is full and egg hatches?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282308/88641) as a duplicate of [What happens if you try to catch a pokemon when you are at your pokemon inventory limit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/282149/88641) For the reasons, king14nyr completely guessed correctly in his comment:

> The question posted by Zalbis probably shouldn't be considered a duplicate, this one does ask about something else. One answer on that question(and the subsequent comments) does talk about Pokemon limit, though, with respect to hatching eggs when full. May be the cause for the VTC, as any answers on this one will probably reiterate what was discussed on that answer.

The vote it self got declined.

But why? My own posts had already been closed as duplicates many times, just because there is a different question where an answer is actually answering my OP.

Where is the difference here?

Comment: I also considered flagging the egg question as a duplicate because of that answer on the other one, but then I thought about a new user searching for both of these questions... the question titles are different enough that if someone was searching specifically for hatching eggs at full capacity, they might not think to look in the "catching Pokemon when full" question, or even more specifically, in the **comments** of the first answer of that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is asking about how the limit applies to **catching Pokémon**:

[What happens if you try to catch a pokemon when you are at your pokemon inventory limit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282149/what-happens-if-you-try-to-catch-a-pokemon-when-you-are-at-your-pokemon-inventor)

This question is asking about how the limit applies to **hatching eggs**:

[Whats happening if your pokemon bag is full and egg hatches?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282308/whats-happening-if-your-pokemon-bag-is-full-and-egg-hatches)

That is why they are being considered as unique questions, and not duplicates.

To be fair, they are similar questions.  You haven't done anything wrong in raising a duplicate flag.  However, the community decided that the questions were different enough to be considered 2 unique question.

Note, the second questions is based on a misconception that the eggs don't count towards the limit until hatched.

Comment: I guess you gave me a great lesson in how SE works with that answer. I assumed as the system applies on every action some reactions none the less its a positive or negative reaction. You might not see the consequences of it imediately or ever. but just when reaching a specific treshhold. But this gave me the expression there is something that requires to be absolute right or wrong in any decision. I got that one wrong so far, didn't I?

Comment: @Zaibis - like is said, you haven't done anything wrong in raising the flag.  It put the question in a review queue, which led to users voting to keep open or close.  The majority decided to keep it open.  The questions are related and similar.  You are only getting it wrong if you are flagging unrelated questions as duplicates.

Comment: @Zaibis Ye it's pretty close, if you raised it at a different time/date it may have been closed. Remember, that it's just regular users that review duplicate flags, so everyone will have slightly different opinions/ be in certain moods at that particular time/etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Duplicate questions are based on the question, not the answers.**

There is no way for someone to know that "What happens when I try to catch a Pokemon when my bag is full?" will answer "What happens when an egg hatches while my bag is full?", even though they are related. The fact that somebody decided to also answer the latter question while writing an answer for the former question is irrelevant.

If this doesn't quite make sense, consider the fact that answers can change over time. It's possible (however unlikely in this case) that the answer that *happens* to address hatching eggs with a full inventory will be edited to remove that information, or even be deleted entirely. You can count on whatever answer is there to always address "what will happen if I try to catch a Pokemon with a full bag", but you *cannot* count on it to always address another question, however closely related it may be.

Here are a few questions to ask yourself when figuring out whether one question is a duplicate of another: Will a user reasonably be able to tell that the answer in the first question will also answer the second question? Will a thorough answer to the first question necessarily contain an answer to the second question? If the answer to the first question changes (such as due to an update), will the answer to the second question definitely change in the same way?  In this case, the answers to all three are a resounding "no", so you absolutely should not have flagged as a duplicate.