# Please make more strict rules about what is to be considered a duplicate and what isn't!

Tags: discussion, site-policies, exact-duplicates

I'm assuming in the following that rules about what is a duplicate are consdiered to be the same over the whole stack exchange network.
If this is not the case, my argument is invalid, but then there is even more need to make clear on what place which thing is considered to be a dupe adn what isn't.

So:

Let me begin here:

If we read [a comment from here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/283273/88641):

> @Zaibis: The answer may be the same but that doesn't mean the question is a duplicate. If somebody is searching for "Can I land on a sun" and see a question "Are there binary/trinary star systems?" then there is no reason to think the latter will answer their question. The relevant information in the answer to that question is pretty much unrelated to the question as asked and was thrown in as an extra bit of trivia.

And we assume he is right, why my post [QT “No such slot” Error [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31562023/2003898) then is a duplicate of [When should Q_OBJECT be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3689714/2003898) ? I mean, ok, the question itself is the answer. But when I'm looking for "What might this 'no such slot' error mean, I certanly wouldn't look up "When should Q_OBJECT be used?" Even if google popped it up to me.

Or lets look at this one: [Has the recent update changed whats the most powerfull attack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/278108/88641) which is asking for "Has there something been changed to X since the last update. Which was then marked as duplicate of a question asking for "What is X?" Ok, 5 days after I asked the question (and also thats the poitn it was marked) An answer to that post made a refference to the update I was refering to. But strictly speaking I asked a yes no question about something having changed and it was considered as beeing duplicate of just asking what it is.

What FMPOV is(admited one might say it isn't) contradicting with this post(s) [When is a different question a duplicate and when it isn't?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11927/88641).

Or this one where I even state content like "I know X is possible, but how it is beeing achieved?" which was marked as duplicate of "Is X possible?" where the answer was evaluating it isn't possible, despeit I KNOW it is...
([Can AV software make sure quarantined files never get executed? [duplicate]](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129097/56061))

Or this one were I ask about a set of threats, which got marked as duplicate of a question asking what a specific mentioned threat does mean: [How can I get infected by computer viruses? [duplicate]](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/122576/56061).

So in generall if all this cases I inspected<sup>1</sup> the pattern slowly begins to get contradicting to me. And when ever I state "But I thought it is like...." People just told me "No, thats wrong you have to be missunderstanding something."

So here you are.

And now please tell me.

- Have I not been wrong at all?
- What am I missunderstanding wrong?
- For the latter case, why there is no specific ruling that more clear explains what (and why) somethign is a duplicate or isn't?

---

<sup>1</sup> What was a lot of effort to relocate all the posts that stored the statute into my memory how to behave on specific sorts of (none)-duplicates

Comment: I don't think it helps to include questions from other sites here. These different sites don't have the exact same policy regarding duplicate questions, and we can't account for or justify the actions of other sites.

Comment: Are they asking the same thing?  No? Then they're not duplicates.  Answers are immaterial.

Comment: @Frank: Pardon me? What are you refering to?

Comment: @murgatroid99: Place that as answer please. As I tryed to transfer from my first lines, I was assuming this is the case. So answering it isn't the case would allready fit for parts of an answer.

Answer (score 7):

First, you can find our current duplicate question policy in [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/duplicate-questions-a-trial).

The first question you reference, the one about No Man's Sky, not only is still open, but it has only one close vote. The comments you got there simply do not reflect site policy or community consensus.

Your question about Pokemon GO is essentially asking for an update to the answer in the linked duplicate. The correct way to do that is to actually ask for that answer to be updated, not to open a new question asking for the same information. And consider this: if the intention in your question is to keep the information in the answer up to date with new game updates, then the answer in that question and in the duplicate should always have the same information. And if your intention is to keep the answer to your question tied to that specific update, then the answer to your question will become out of date and useless, and the answer to the duplicate will stay useful.